# Error configuring action processing pipeline

Tags: jboss, esb

Kindly help in debugging the below issue.

Summary about the Environment

1) We are having two different esb box and services box. In Esb box, all esb are deployed and in services box, all services are deployed.

2) WSDL are kepl locally on esb box and jboss-esb.xml is picking up the wsdl by

```
2012-12-19 11:04:46,056 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (Thread-2) Error installing to Start: name=jboss.esb.vfs:///opt/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/NotificationServiceESB.esb state=Create: org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.lifecycle.ManagedLifecycleException: Error configuring action processing pipeline
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.MessageAwareListener.doInitialise(MessageAwareListener.java:192) [:]
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.lifecycle.AbstractManagedLifecycle.initialise(AbstractManagedLifecycle.java:133) [:]
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.lifecycle.ManagedLifecycleController.initialiseInstances(ManagedLifecycleController.java:109) [:]
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.lifecycle.ManagedLifecycleController.start(ManagedLifecycleController.java:66) [:]
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.as6.EsbDeployment.start(EsbDeployment.java:234) [:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_16]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_16]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_16]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_16]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:202) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doInstall(ServiceController.java:653) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.register(ServiceController.java:356) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerRegistrationLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerRegistrationLifecycleCallback.java:104)[:6.0.0.Final]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor312.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_16]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_16]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_16]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:305) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:2018) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1983) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1091) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:443) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.java:44)[:6.0.0.Final]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor315.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_16]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_16]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_16]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:305) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:2018) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1983) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1091) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:182) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_16]
Caused by: org.jboss.soa.esb.ConfigurationException: Unexpected exception during lifecycle initialisation
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline.initialise(ActionProcessingPipeline.java:402) [:]
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.MessageAwareListener.doInitialise(MessageAwareListener.java:188) [:]
... 118 more
Caused by: org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.ActionLifecycleException: Got an error while processing EJB method [initializeQueue]
at org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.AQEJBProcessor.initialise(AQEJBProcessor.java:58) [:]
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor.initialise(OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor.java:123) [:]
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline.initialise(ActionProcessingPipeline.java:397) [:]
... 119 more
Caused by: org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.ActionLifecycleException: Could not lookup NotificationAQListenerBean/remote
at org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.AQEJBProcessor.getEjb3FromJndi(AQEJBProcessor.java:90) [:]
at org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.AQEJBProcessor.initialise(AQEJBProcessor.java:53) [:]
... 121 more
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: 10.20.90.173:1099 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1690)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1761)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:695)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.AQEJBProcessor.getEjb3FromJndi(AQEJBProcessor.java:87)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.AQEJBProcessor.initialise(AQEJBProcessor.java:53)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor.initialise(OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline.initialise(ActionProcessingPipeline.java:397)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.MessageAwareListener.doInitialise(MessageAwareListener.java:188)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.lifecycle.AbstractManagedLifecycle.initialise(AbstractManagedLifecycle.java:133)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.lifecycle.ManagedLifecycleController.initialiseInstances(ManagedLifecycleController.java:109)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.lifecycle.ManagedLifecycleController.start(ManagedLifecycleController.java:66)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.as6.EsbDeployment.start(EsbDeployment.java:234)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:202)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doInstall(ServiceController.java:653)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.register(ServiceController.java:356)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerRegistrationLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerRegistrationLifecycleCallback.java:104)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor312.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:305)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:2018)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1983)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1091)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:443)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.java:44)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor315.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:305)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:2018)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1983)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1091)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:182)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106)
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143)
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151)
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
```

I have tried to deploy the esb with
deployment.xml

```
<jbossesb-deployment>    
<depends>jboss.esb:deployment=jbossesb.esb</depends>    
<depends>jboss.esb:deployment=soap.esb</depends>    
<depends>jboss.esb:deployment=spring.esb</depends>    
<depends>jboss.esb:deployment=jbrules.esb</depends>    
</jbossesb-deployment>
```

and also tried with deployment.xml

```
<jbossesb-deployment>    
<depends>jboss.esb:deployment=jbossesb.esb</depends>    
<depends>jboss.esb:deployment=soap.esb</depends>    
<depends>jboss.esb:deployment=spring.esb</depends>    
</jbossesb-deployment>
```

But in both cases it is giving same exception

Also tried on both jboss-6.0.0 and jboss-5 .1.0 but same exception.

Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: What's the exception - I can't see it in your post.

Comment: Thanks for replying

[Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server /servicesIP:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server /10.20.90.173:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]]]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1780) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:695) [:5.0.5.Final]
        
        ... 107 more

Comment: The jboss is binding in this IP and port (10.20.90.173:1099) ?

Answer (score 0):

may the jndi is not correctly reference in the deployment.xml 
see the correct Class: reference in the ejb proyect deploy.
reviews all entries of the class ejb, like: "@Remote" and "@Resource"